# How much water would remain at the poles of these planets?

Tags: science-based, planets, climate, weather

My binary terrestrial planets are roughly the size of earth and they are tidally locked with one another. They are 12,000 miles (19,312 km) apart. That distance is based off of this article, http://phys.org/news/2014-12-binary-terrestrial-planets.html, which suggests a likely distance of only three planet radii.

No axial tilt. The atmosphere is similar to Earth. I know the gravitational pull would cause these planets to bulge toward one another. My question is: how much, if any, water on these planets would remain at the poles?

Comment: Depends on how much water there is on the planet, remember the rotation of the pair pushes the water back.   Planets are too close though, your setup would collapse.

Answer (score 1):

At 12,000 miles, this first reminded me of another question about two colliding planets (not sure how to link to related questions) and the effects on atmosphere and surface gravity.  If we accept that these two bodies would orbit one another relatively stably, http://www.calctool.org/CALC/phys/astronomy/planet_orbit showed me that they would orbit one another once every 111 minutes.  I went to http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1360312100 and plugged in a few combinations of masses and distances, with the following results:

- If our moon were moved in to a distance of 12,000 miles, the tide force would be more than 7,000 times as powerful as it is now.
- If the mass of the object at 12,000 miles were increased to that of the Earth, the tide force would be over 600,000 times as powerful as it is now.

Would there be any water left at the poles?  It seems as though any liquid water would be piled up into *Interstellar*-level tides at the near and far sides of the planets.  If we can imagine frozen water at the poles remaining through the "kissing" event that established this orbit (I can't imagine that - it sounds deeply apocalyptic) then it might remain frozen at the poles for a very brief time until tidal heating melted it all and it made its way to the party.

So...probably not.

Comment: If planets are tidally locked and their orbit is circular, tides are just a memory of a distant past.

Answer (score 0):

12 000 miles is only an Earth diameter and a half away. That kind of system cannot form. The masses would tear each other apart and form one solid planet soon enough.

Comment: Using the equation for the Roche limit as $R=1.26R_M(M_M/M_m)^{1/3}$, with both masses equal, we get a separation distance of $1.26 R_M$. This is less than the sum of the radii of both planets, so they'll be stable at any separation.

Comment: @ckersch You are just taking an ideal case there... the simplest form. Read up on the Roche Limit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit That system will not form.

Comment: Any source supporting "That system will not form"? 12000 miles is outside the Roche limit for *fluid* bodies.

Comment: @ckersch I can give you one heck of a reason for it: you are hoping that two planets will form well away from of the bottom of the gravity well... that 12 million billion billion kilograms of star dust will climb out of the gravity well, in opposite directions, to an altitude of 6000 miles each and form levitating planets. Unless some **god** made these two planets, all ready and done... and then set them spinning like that, there is no way in hell you are going to get that. And since the tag is "science-based": no gods allowed.

Comment: In the article I linked, they theorize such planets are the result of "'kissing' collisions where two similar mass bodies encounter each other and become a bound system because of the energy lost in the strong tides raised on each other in the encounter. The resulting binary can then persist for billions of years provided it forms well away from the central star, at half an astronomical unit (the distance between the Earth and Sun) or more."

Read more at: http://phys.org/news/2014-12-binary-terrestrial-planets.html#jCp

Comment: @Manda You cannot — in any but the most freakish of improbabilities — have two celestial bodies come sailing from two different directions, collide without breaking apart and then end up with a nice circular orbit around a center of mass that close. That kind of thing is so massively improbable that people would use it as a proof of the non-existence of God... *"...because the planet duo is a dead give-away isn't it. It proves you exist, and so therefore you don't, QED". "Oh dear..." says God "...I hadn't thought of that" and promptly vanishes in a puff of logic.*

Comment: A Caltech study says it's a possibility, the result of a grazing collision.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors They would need to have fairly low relative initial velocities, as mentioned in the article Manda cited. The central idea of that paper is that a grazing collision would have too much angular velocity to coalesce into a single planet, a hypothesis which was supported by their simulations of that process.

Comment: I took a look at the Wikipedia page of "Double planet" and I must say that was an appalling mess. I found the study you are talking about. (Ryan, Nakajima, Stevenson, 2014). And here is what they say: "The long computational times for these simulation make it difficult to fully map the phase space of encounters for which this outcome is likely but the indications are that the probability is not vanishingly small...". so they have some "indications" that the probability it might work is "not vanishingly small"... while not at all talking about the probabilities of vagabonding planets.

Comment: So... **sure**... if you tailor your story and just flat out state "here is an instance where everything was just right for this"... then you might end up with something like what you are seeking. But do not expect it to be very credible, nor to not have your readers raise a skeptical eyebrow. And if you hope to win them over by exposition that states that a **simulation** shows that "the probability is not vanishingly small", then I dare say you got your work cut out for you in trying to make that into a credible story. Kudos to you if you succeed... but I am not holding my breath over it.

Comment: Low probability events happen all the time. If it's physically feasible and the computer simulations indicate it's so, then fine. Most readers won't worry about the low probability of this double planet's existence. @MichaelKamerfors you're obviously a straight down the line scientific purist. Nothing wrong with that, we need someone keep us all from wandering off track. Thanks for the warning about the mess of the Wikipedia double planet page.

Comment: @a4android Well thank you for that analysis  of what I am. 2 things: 1) you're wrong and 2) it's not relevant to the question or answer. Questioner tagged this as "science based" and got an answer accordingly. Do you have a problem with that? If so, don't waste our or your time psychoanalysing your fellow SE visitors because you suck at it and it is irrelevant. Focus on the questions and answer.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors I can't believe you just criticized a4android for being off topic when several of your earlier comments are completely unrelated rants about God/gods and predictions about how my readers will react to my worldbuilding. I asked a question about water at the poles. I don't mind you criticizing the setup for my binary planets. That's a part of healthy discourse and, if it's true, important information. However, your tone during this exchange has been extremely combative and that doesn't promote the exchange of ideas and information. It shuts it down.

Comment: @Manda I have no tolerance for people that do not discuss the issue and instead attack the **person** out of spite, pride or simply for a lack of things to say.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerford Look I'm stunned. My remark about you being a scientific purist wasn't an attack. To me, that's a compliment. Not psychoanalysis at all. I was commenting on your statement about the probability of the double planet. Yes, even if it's remarkably low probability, then low probability events do happen. Statistics and probability are science, so it seemed relevant. I apologise for any offence no matter how inadvertent it may have been.

Comment: @a4android Compliment noted and heartilly appreciated. :) That said: **please** stick to the issue, and do not involve our persons in the discussion, alright? I am sorry for the spiked attitude, I regret if that has caused upset. I will moderate myself better henceforth.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Thanks. I wasn't upset. I was completely blindsided by an unexpected response. My remarks weren't intended to be about your person. I shall be more careful in future discussion. Though inevitably our beliefs and attitudes can and do seep through into how we interpret the science. If I did that, I expect to be called out for it. Glad this has been settled in a civil manner. Looking forward to more robust discussions about the science on SE.